# Spring . Rest Assured

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, rest-assured

API signature :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "uploadImage", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {"application/sd-service", "application/json"})

@ResponseBody

public ImageUploadResponse uploadImage(@RequestParam(value = "channel", required=false) Channel channel, @RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam(value = "responseProtocol")Protocol responseProtocol)
```

I am using rest assured to send the following request to upload an image file .

```
Response res=RestAssured

                .given()
                .contentType("image/jpeg"
                .body("{"responseProtocol":"PROTOCOL_JSON","channel":"WEB"}")
                .multiPart(fileItem)
                .when()
                .log()
                .all()
                .post("http://x.y.z.a:8080/service/contactus/v2/uploadImage")
                .andReturn();
```

where String userDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");

```
File fileItem= new File(userDir +"//src//main//resources//1.jpeg");
```

is the image file. But no results because of error mentioned below:

```
Getting org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: The current request is not a multipart request for below case:
```

Comment: Can you try with the   .contentType("multipart/form-data")

Answer (score 1):

```
res = RestAssured
            .given()
            .contentType("multipart/form-data")
            .accept("application/json")
            .formParameter("channel", "WEB")
            .formParameter("responseProtocol", "PROTOCOL_JSON")
            .body(request.getBody())
            .multiPart("file",fileItem,"image/jpeg")
            .when()
            .log()
            .all()
            .post(request.getURI())
            .andReturn();
```

using form parameters solves it.